# Global in function decorator

Tags: global-variables, global, decorator

```
some_global = 15
. 
. 
. 
@some_decorator(some_global)
def someFunction(): 
. 
. 
. 
class SomeClass:
    def someMethod(self):
        global some_global
        some_global = 5
```

In the above abstracted version of my code, when the global is passed into the decorator after the method has been run and the value of the global changed, the parameter is still recognised in the decorator as 15, instead of 5. Is this a known problem? Or must be an issue with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on order of lines of your code. If our decorator calls with a argument before the some method, then some_global has its initial value, otherwise if you call some method before the decorator, then global variable has its changed value.

with this code:

```
some_global = 15


def some_decorator(val):
    print("decorator val: {}".format(val))
    print("decorator global: {}".format(some_global))

    def real_decorator(function):
        def wrapper():
            function()

        return wrapper

    return real_decorator


class SomeClass:
    def some_method(self):
        global some_global
        some_global = 5
        print("method: {}".format(some_global))
```

if you write

```
@some_decorator(some_global)
def some_function():
    print("function: {}".format(some_global))


SomeClass().some_method()

some_function()
```

then output will be

```
decorator val: 15
decorator global: 15
method: 5
function: 5
```

but output of this code:

```
SomeClass().some_method()


@some_decorator(some_global)
def some_function():
    print("function: {}".format(some_global))


some_function()
```

will be:

```
method: 5
decorator val: 5
decorator global: 5
function: 5
```

I strongly suggest you that don't use global variables.

In your case you can use it directly in your decorator's wrapper:

some_global = 15

```
def real_decorator(function):
    print("decorator: {}".format(some_global))

    def wrapper():
        print("wrapper: {}".format(some_global))
        function()

    return wrapper


class SomeClass:
    def some_method(self):
        global some_global
        some_global = 5
        print("method: {}".format(some_global))


@real_decorator
def some_function():
    print("function: {}".format(some_global))


SomeClass().some_method()

some_function()
```

in this code, variable's value in wrapper only depends on order of function calls in the bottom of code and is equal to its value in some function:

```
SomeClass().some_method()

some_function()
```